# R data table: strangely poor performance in subsetting

Tags: r, optimization, data.table

I was under the impression that `data.table` is extremely well optimized, so I was quite surprised to see this:

```
library(data.table)

SimData <- data.table(ID = sample(1:4e5, 4e6, replace = TRUE),
                      DATE = sample(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = "day"),
                                    4e6, replace = TRUE))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(SimData[ID==1&DATE>="2005-01-01"])
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(SimData[ID==1][DATE>="2005-01-01"])
```

The two solutions are quite obviously the same, yet there is more than an order of magnitude difference in runtime. Is it possible that `data.table` performs so poorly with the first form? (I.e., that it can't automatically optimize this call.) Or I overlook something here...?

Answer (score 4):

The long operation is `SimData[DATE>="2005-01-01"]` because it returns millions of rows.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(SimData[DATE>="2005-01-01"],SimData[ID==1])
Unit: microseconds
                          expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 SimData[DATE >= "2005-01-01"] 32542.8 44549.55 51323.53 47529.75 50258.10 117396.3   100
              SimData[ID == 1]   820.0  1043.55  1397.79  1435.15  1688.25   2302.5   100
```

`SimData[ID == 1]` is much shorter as it returns only a few rows,

When you execute `SimData[ID==1&DATE>="2005-01-01"]`, you force both evaluations on all rows.

With `SimData[ID==1][DATE>="2005-01-01"]` the quick operation is done first, and the subsequent filter is also quick because applied on only a few row.

As mentioned by @jangorecki, there is a [room for improvement in that matter](http://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4105).

Comment: I am confused. From my run of benchmarking `SimData[ID == 1 & DATE >= "2005-01-01"]` (44 ms) was faster than `SimData[ID == 1][DATE >= "2005-01-01"]` (1734 ms). Where ms is mean milliseconds

Comment: did you try to put both expressions together in the same `microbenchmark`?

Comment: Well spotted. I re-ran with both methods inside one single `microbenchmark` function. Now it all makes sense. `SimData[ID==1&DATE>="2005-01-01"]` (30091 ms) where `SimData[ID==1][DATE>="2005-01-01"]` (6842 ms)

Comment: I see that point @Waldi, but what I find surprising is that `data.table` does not automatically recognize this optimization possibility. I was under the impression that `data.table` is heavily optimized, and the above proves that `SimData[ID==1&DATE>="2005-01-01"]` _can_ be run faster, and _much_ faster. Is it intentional that `data.table` doesn't recognize this possibility? Or I am wrong in claiming that this is an easy optimization? Or is it simply a room for improvement...?

Comment: There is a room for improvement in that matter, and it is already described in https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4105 having a branch called `fwhich` that is meant to address cases like that.

Comment: Thank you very much @jangorecki! The opening post in the issue you linked is my exact question... If you could post your comment as an answer, I'd happily accept it.

Comment: Waldi answer is good enough IMO, my answer would just repeat a lot what he wrote.

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` optimizes the queries like `X==x`, and `ID==1` is in this form thus the first time you run this query it takes a while but after that calling the same query is very fast. In your case second run of the query `SimData[ID==1]` is very fast and the returned data table is very small which makes the second query also fast.